# Float value in Tkinter canvas coordinates

Tags: python, canvas, floating-point, tkinter

How I can use float coordinates when I create a canvas object?
For example:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import math

    main=Tk()
    w=Canvas(main, height=100, width=100)
    w.grid(row=0, column=0)
    for y in range(100):
        for x in range(100):
            if y==math.sin(x):
                w.create_oval(x, y, x, y)
        x=0
```

It returns blank form...
So, how I can use also float number as coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You've got several problems.

1. `sin(x)` will never be greater than 1 or less than -1, so it makes no sense to check `y` up to 100. Your whole loop structure is wrong.
2. If you want to match `x` to integer values of `sin(x)` (1, 0, and -1), you need to multiply `x` by `math.pi/2`
3. Because of the way floating point math works, `0==sin(pi)` or `0==sin(2*pi)` will not be true, you need to check something like `-0.01 < sin(pi) < 0.01`.
4. `create_oval` need two different pairs of `x, y` -- an upper left and lower right. You're passing it the same value for both points, so you would only ever see maybe a single dot if you did get to this point.
5. The `x=0` is unnecessary, as a new `range(100)` will be created for `x` every time you go to a new `y` value.

Edit: @eryksun pointed out in a comment that #4 may be your intention. If so, that part is right, and the whole thing makes more sense -- it looks like you're trying to plot the sine curve. It also means you don't necessarily want to multiply `x` by `math.pi / 2`.

If that's the case, your code could be something like (changing as little as possible):

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

main=Tk()
w=Canvas(main, height=100, width=100)
w.grid(row=0, column=0)
for x in range(100):
    # this makes the sine curve y-value 
    # stretch from 0 to 100 instead of -1 to 1
    y = 49.5 - math.sin(x) * 49.5
    w.create_oval(x, y, x, y)
```

Comment: @eryksun It wasn't my intention to guess too much at what he wanted it to look like. I change the first thing you mentioned because this way you at least won't try to draw outside the window; the second I won't try to guess what he wants, I mentioned the issue in #2.